# Basic Authentication does not work for Search API in Azure DEVOPS

Tags: rest, search, azure-devops, basic-authentication, servicenow

Issue :Basic Authentication does not work for  Search API in Azure DEVOPS

API NAME :**Work Item Search Results - Fetch Work Item Search Results**

API:

POST `https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/search/workitemsearchresults?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

Observation : it works fine when i use **PAT**(Personal Access Token) but does not when i use **Basic Authentication** in a REST Msg..I am doing all this in ServiceNow

> Error: Method failed:
>   (/rahulreddy0193/rahul_1359/_apis/search/workitemsearchresults) with
>   code: 401 - Invalid username/password combo

But I am 100% confident its not username/pwd...because same authentication works for other REST Msgs

Comment: This error message is not send from azure devops. Since you can achieve succeed with PAT, means you have enough permission on our side. This message should caused by ServiceNow but unfortunately I am not very familiar with that. For suggestion, what about this thread: https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=29658baddbd8dbc01dcaf3231f961972

Comment: This error message should not relevant with Azure Devops. Since you can run this api with PAT. which means you have enough permission on VSTS. This error should be the one in ServiceNow that I am not very good at. As you said its not **username/pwd**, could you express more on how do you call this API in servicenow? Also, as suggestion, what about this thread: https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=29658baddbd8dbc01dcaf3231f961972

Comment: https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/search/workitemsearchresults?api-version=5.1-preview.1


this searching the whole board, is there a way to add a filter just to search on title(system.title) itself, i have tried adding the filter system.title it doesnt work

Scenario: if i want to search "ABC" from REST API it is returning the result even if "ABC" exists in description of the story or discussion of the story....so is there a way to search and return the results just based on title and not anything else